# why core data is cleared when app is relaunch in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

I am using core data as local DB to save local data in my iOS App. When the app is terminated and relaunched again then local data is cleared from core data. I am calling **saveContext()** from **applicationDidEnterBackground** and **applicationWillTerminate** methods. One thing is that I have changed the core data version. This change will do any effect on clear data after the relaunched app.

**saveContext Method - :**

```
func saveContext () -> Bool {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        var saveFlag = false
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
                saveFlag = true
            } catch {
                saveFlag = false
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        return saveFlag
    }
```

**Note :** From above saveContext() method, Not goes inside context.hasChanges condition. So, not print an error message. It goes outside the condition and returns **saveFlag** as **false.**

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant core data code, your error handling code and any errors you are receiving.

Comment: can you please look in to it. i have just edit my question and added the code.

Comment: can you also post code how you add values to your moc?

Comment: My code is working fine when the app is in the foreground and background state. But, when I close the app and again relaunches then local core database is got clear.

Answer (score 0):

`var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate`

````
        let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
        var saveFlag = false
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
                saveFlag = true
            } catch {
                saveFlag = false
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        return saveFlag
    }```

Please try the above code
````